How to specify download URL and save with a specified filename?
I have several files to download which have the same filename. Is there any way to specify the target/save file name so that the file that is being downloaded saved as the filename I have specified next to it or using some format?
I have 4,000+ files to download and I can specify the source URL and target filename, but is there any utility/tool which will allow me to specify that?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There are many tools to download and rename duplicate files (e.g., https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11105), but this is not s software recommendation site. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

As I am using Windows, I was able to create a .bat file and downloaded the wget command's windows version and used that.
I imported the file list into excel, copied url into another col., in the copied col. I removed the url and kept the filename, made them unique by prefixing a number.
Added wget command in the first col.
Second col was the url of the image
Third col had the -O option to specify the output filename
Fourth col had the unique filename we created earlier by prefixing the number.
Copied all the above and pasted into a text editor, removed tab with space and saved the file as a .bat file.
Opened command prompt and ran the bat file and all the files got downloaded one by one with the changed name.
Maybe there's an easier way but this worked for me.
Thank you.
